# Ajax retrieves html instead of json

Tags: ajax, laravel-5

I'm having a problem with an ajax method, it retrieves an html file instead of json and I have no clue why it is happening because it works perfectly in my home route, but when I try to implement it in my create route, the ajax method doesn't work right

route file

```
Route::get('home', 'HomeController@index');
Route::get('suggestions',[
'as' => 'suggestions_path',
'uses' => 'SuggestionController@index'
]);
Route::get('suggestions/create',[
'as' => 'suggestions_path',
'uses' => 'SuggestionController@create'
]);
Route::get('ajax_scrap_app',[
'as' => 'ajax_scrap_app_path',
'uses' => 'AjaxController@getAppOpenGraph'
]);
```

HomeController

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Level;

class HomeController extends Controller {

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }

    /**
     * Show the application dashboard to the user.
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $levels = Level::all();
        //dd($levels);


        return view('home')->with('levels',$levels);
    }

}
```

SuggestionController

```
    <?php namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Http\Requests\SuggestionRequest;
use App\Level;
use App\Scrap;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use App\Suggestion;

class SuggestionController extends Controller {

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }
    /**
     * Despliega todas las sugerencias hechas por el usuario
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function index()
    {

        $suggestions = Auth::user()->suggestions()->latest()->get();
        return view('suggestions.all')->with('suggestions',$suggestions);
    }

    /**
     * Despliega la forma para crear una sugerencia
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        $levels = Level::all();
        return view('suggestions.create')->with('levels',$levels);
    }

    /**
     * Guarda la nueva sugerencia
     * @param SuggestionRequest $request
     * @return Response
     */
    public function store(SuggestionRequest $request)
    {
        $suggestion = new Suggestion($request->all());
        Auth::user()->suggestions()->save($suggestion);
        return redirect('suggestions');
    }

    /**
     * Despliega una sugerencia específica, basados en el id
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return Response
     */
    public function show($id)
    {
        $openGraph = new Scrap();
        $suggestion = Suggestion::find($id);

        return view('suggestions.show')->with(['suggestion' => $suggestion, 'openGraph' => $openGraph]);
    }

    /**
     * Despliega la forma para editar una sugerencia específica, basados en el id
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return Response
     */
    public function edit($id)
    {
        $suggestion = Suggestion::find($id);
        return view('suggestions.edit')->with('suggestion',$suggestion);
    }

    /**
     * Actualiza la sugerencia
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @param SuggestionRequest $request
     * @return Response
     */
    public function update($id, SuggestionRequest $request)
    {
        $suggestion = Suggestion::find($id);
        $suggestion->update($request->all());
        return redirect('suggestions');
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return Response
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        //
    }

}
```

here is my ajax method so far

```
$('#app_url').on('focusout',function(e){
    var appURL = e.target.value;
    console.log("appURL: "+appURL);
    /* AJAX */
    $.get('ajax_scrap_app?app_url='+appURL, function (data) {
        console.log(data);
        console.log("THIS IS THE TITLE: "+data[0].title);
        console.log("THIS IS THE DESCRIPTION: "+data[0].description);
        console.log("THIS IS THE IMAGE: "+data[0].image);
        $('#app_title').val(data[0].title);
        $('#app_description').val(data[0].description);
        $('#app_image').val(data[0].image);

    });
});
```

this is AjaxController

```
public function getAppOpenGraph(){
    $scrap = new Scrap();
    $url = Input::get('app_url');
    $scrap::setUrl($url);
    $title = $scrap::getOpenGraphTitle();
    $description = $scrap::getOpenGraphDescription();
    $image = $scrap::getOpenGraphImg();
    $openGraph = [['title'=>$title,'description'=>$description,'image'=>$image]];
    return Response::json($openGraph);

}
```

OUTPUT from home page (http://localhost/exaproject/public/home)

```
appURL: https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/crossy-road-endless-arcade/id924373886?mt=8&v0=WWW-NAUS-ITSTOP100-FREEAPPS&l=en&ign-mpt=uo%3D4
[Object]
THIS IS THE TITLE: Crossy Road - Endless Arcade Hopper
THIS IS THE DESCRIPTION: Get Crossy Road - Endless Arcade Hopper on the App Store. See screenshots and ratings, and read customer reviews.
THIS IS THE IMAGE: http://a3.mzstatic.com/us/r30/Purple7/v4/20/7a/c2/207ac26e-66f1-1ee0-1f70-c4733a9015a1/icon320x320.png
```

OUTPUT form create page (http://localhost/exaproject/public/suggestions/create)

```
appURL: https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/crossy-road-endless-

arcade/id924373886?mt=8&v0=WWW-NAUS-ITSTOP100-FREEAPPS&l=en&ign-mpt=uo%3D4
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Apprendiendo</title>

    <link href="http://localhost/exaproject/public/css/app.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">-->
    <!-- Fonts -->
    <link href='//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
</head>
<body>
            <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle Navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Apprendiendo</a>
        </div>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li><a href="http://localhost/exaproject/public">Home</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Sugerencias <span class="caret"></span></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                        <li><a href="http://localhost/exaproject/public/suggestions/create">Crear Sugerencia</a></li>
                        <li><a href="http://localhost/exaproject/public/search">B&uacute;scar Sugerencias</a></li>
                        <li><a href="http://localhost/exaproject/public/suggestions">Mis Sugerencias</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="http://localhost/exaproject/public/plan">Mi Plan</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://localhost/exaproject/public/profile">Mi perfil</a></li>

            </ul>

            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Angel Salazar <span class="caret"></span></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                            <li><a href="http://localhost/exaproject/public/auth/logout">Logout</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>    
    <div class="container">

    </div>

    <!-- Scripts -->
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://localhost/exaproject/public/js/app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>

THIS IS THE TITLE: undefined
THIS IS THE DESCRIPTION: undefined
THIS IS THE IMAGE: undefined
```

I would appreciate some help !!!

Comment: could you please show the code from `SuggestionController@create` and `SuggestionController@index`?

Comment: sorry, I forgot those, but I've already edited my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Views by default return a string content like you did:

```
public function create()
{
    $levels = Level::all();

    // here you are calling an hmlt/text output
    return view('suggestions.create')->with('levels',$levels);
}
```

That is the main reason why you are receiving html response. There are two options:

1. Return the rendered view inside of json:

   ```
   public function create()
   {
       $levels = Level::all();

       // here you are calling an hmlt/text output
       $output = view('suggestions.create')->with('levels',$levels)->render();
       return response()->json(['html' => $output]);
   }
   ```

   By this way, you can read the response in ajax callable as json like `data.html`
2. Avoid returning views. If you want json plain data, then works for that:

   ```
   public function create()
   {
       // Do some logic here

       // Return json data
       return response()->json(['foo' => 'bar']);
   }
   ```

Finally, looks like you are working with RESTful controllers, that is ok, but resources controllers do not were made to return html data.

Comment: Oh thanks buddy, it totally works and I appreciate your time, but it´s not what I want to achieve, maybe I didn't get myself clear, I have to populate a form with the json response, I want to get the output from home page, like it is in my question, but for some reason it doesn't work when using it in my create form

Answer (score 0):

I made it work, I don't know exactly why, but those are the changes I made

Route.php

```
Route::get('suggestions/create/ajax_scrap_app',[
'as' => 'ajax_scrap_app_path',
'uses' => 'AjaxController@getAppOpenGraph'
]);
```

Ajax method

```
$('#app_url').on('focusout',function(e){
        var appURL = e.target.value;
        console.log("appURL: "+appURL);
        /* AJAX */
        $.get('create/ajax_scrap_app?app_url='+appURL, function (data) {
            console.log(data);
            console.log("THIS IS THE TITLE: "+data[0].title);
            console.log("THIS IS THE DESCRIPTION: "+data[0].description);
            console.log("THIS IS THE IMAGE: "+data[0].image);
            $('#app_title').val(data[0].title);
            $('#app_description').val(data[0].description);
            $('#app_image').val(data[0].image);

        },'json');
    });
```